# Link an ENS domain name with an IP address

Tags: ethereum

Is it possible to point an ENS domain to an IP address. Not an IPFS hash or Onion site, just a regular old IP address.

There are many tutorials listing how to point an ENS domain name to an IPFS hash, or use some other centralized service. Unfortunately they don't tell me much else. I'm getting the feeling that the answer is *no, you can't do that*.